# How to deploy HTML to heroku?

Tags: php, html, heroku, web

I have `home.html` file, basically it's the whole source code of HTML. I also have `index.php`:`<?php include_once("home.html"); ?>`. It keeps on saying language is not detected.

> !     No default language could be detected for this app.
>               HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically.
>               See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
>    !     Push failed

Comment: Why not using the link in the warning to get more explanation?

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question in your title, Heroku isn't really suited to hosting only static HTML. It is designed for running web *applications*, not web *sites*. I don't think Heroku even has an HTML-only buildpack, and I would strongly advise using another host for that purpose. There are many options for hosting static HTML at very low cost.

However, it sounds like what you *actually* want is to host PHP. Initially, Heroku's build process attempts to detect the language of your application using some basic heuristics and then uses an appropriate [buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks). (After it detects a buildpack once that buildpack will be used again in the future.)

To get Heroku to detect a PHP application you [*must* include a `composer.json` file in the root directory of your project](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-php#overview):

> Heroku PHP Support will be applied to applications only when the application has a file named `composer.json` in the root directory. Even if an application has no Composer dependencies, it must include an empty `composer.json` in order to be recognized as a PHP application.

If you are using Composer to manage dependencies, you must also include your `composer.lock` file.